# How to create a widget with react for integration in other react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if it is possible to write a widget with React and distribute it as a CDN to integrate it into another application react?

The idea:
I have several applications in writing with react and I would like to have a banner common to all applications without having to rewrite it in each of them. The goal is to facilitate the updates of this banner.

My widget named toolBar works perfectly when I do npm start.

I have build my toolBar and add the script generate in the folder build into an other app named myAppTest.

My toolBar work and the other app to. However, the css and toolBar images are not loaded properly when launching myAppTest.

What is the best way pleasure ?

Comment: What are your limitations?

Comment: for the moment i have no limit.

Comment: `if it is possible to write a widget with React`   If by widget you mean Component, yes, it's possible, as long as your component has all required dependencies to function, your good to go.

Comment: I mean have you tried it and failed? Is there some specific problem you are facing?

Comment: i have edit my post for more details

Comment: *For the moment my bar works but I can not integrate it in a react react* - what did you try and what is the problem? The answer to your current question is "somehow, depending on your case". Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement for your problem.

Comment: it s hard. I have re edit my post for more information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by "integrating a widget with a react application" you mean a stand-alone react application (your widget) that needs to get data and pass data back to another application (react application in your case) then it's totally doable.
I even [posted an article with a tutorial](https://www.debuggr.io/react-micro-frontends) on how to do just that.

Basically the gist of it is that most of us learned that each `react` application has an entry point that run this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, myContainer);
```

As in fire and forget approach.

But actually we can run `ReactDOM.render` as much as we want, it won't re-mount our application but instead will trigger the diffing for the tree.

> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React element.

So what we can do is wrap it in a function and expose it globally so other code on the page can run it.

A pattern i use is to accept props with that function and it will pass it on to the `<App/>` via `ReactDOM.render`.

For example:

```
window.CoolWidget = {
    mount: (props, container) => {
        ReactDOM.render(<CoolWidget {...props} />, container);
    },
    unmount: (container) => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    }
}
```

And the consumers of your widget can run it:

```
window.CoolWidget.mount({widgetProp: someValue, onLogin: function(){...}}, myContainer)
```

The best thing with this approach is that they can convert this code to a react component (or maybe even you can do it for them!):

```
class CoolWidgetWrapper extends PureComponent {

    // create a ref so we can pass the element to mount and unmount
    widgetRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        // initial render with props
        window.CoolWidget.mount(this.props, this.widgetRef.current);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps !== this.props){
            window.CoolWidget.mount(this.props, this.widgetRef.current);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        window.CoolWidget.unmount(this.widgetRef.current);
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.widgetRef}></div>
    }
}
```

And this is how they will use it:

```
<CoolWidgetWrapper someProp={someValue} onLogin={someFunc} />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You perfectly understood my request !! I will watch your tutorial thanks. I will validate if I arrived there.

Comment: What did you modify in your webpack config so that your build generates only one script file?

Comment: I changed the [output](https://github.com/sag1v/react-external-integration-starter/blob/master/counter-app/config/webpack.config.prod.js)

Comment: one question plz, when i load my app on other page that home, i get this error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" 
if i load my app on the home and navigate on other page the widget work fine do you have idead why ?

Comment: @A.Vincent This other page, does it include the `react` and `react-dom` source files? without them, `JSX` is not supported as its not really JavaScript.

Comment: i load the widget in index.html on my main React app. I create component as your tutorial. I use react router . And i think that reason for this error. 
after many hours i found this solution. I have add <base href="/" /> on my head. Now all my app works perfectly.

Comment: This answer and accompanying blog post deserve way more credit than Sagiv is getting here.